# calling lightbox from an ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender

Tags: z-index, lightbox

I am launching the lightbox from an  ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender the red link in capture1, the lightbox opens BEHIND the C how do get this on top?

i tried setting the  z-index: 10009; for the .lightboxOverlay and .lightbox and the lightbox is still behind the .lightboxOverlay